# PHP Graph API to disolay photo from album

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, photos

I wrote a php script that gets random articles from my DB and display it on my Facebook page using the graph API, I was about to do the same with the images that I want to post but I noticed that it won't be efficient because getting the images in random will mean that the same image might be uploaded more than once in more than one occasion

The efficient way would be uploading all the images to a Facebook album instead of the DB and then use the graph API to post the images from the album the problem now is that I can't figure how to do so.

Comment: you cant figure out how to upload into a facebook album? or use the api to post the images?

Comment: I can upload the photos to an album but I don't know how to display each uploaded image on its own post using the graph api, please help?

Answer (score 0):

You can move the images you have already uploaded,

otherwise, mark the rows you've already uploaded to facebook and exclude these rows from your select query.

Comment: Would you be able to give me a sample code on how I can do this?